# Cursor loading issue

Tags: xna

I have a few questions about a custom cursor in XNA, because I'm new.

1. I'm using:

   ```
   cursorTex = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ico.png");
   ```

   where cursorTex is a 2D Texture to load the cursor. However, it says file not found - even though it is in my Content directory. What's wrong and how do I fix this?
2. How can I set `onMouseOver` on certain buttons to react to change the cursor's image? And also, how do I change the image when the user is holding click?

Comment: It is necessary to add the png to your content project in the solution explorer. Have you done that? If so, try it with just "ico" instead of "ico.png". if not, right click the content project in the solution explorer, select add existing item, and navigate to & select the ico.png

Comment: @SteveH I did that, and it said Error loading "Other\ico". File not found. And yes, I do have ico.png in my "Other" folder of my Content.

Comment: It's not enough to have it in the folder. it has to be added to the content project.

Comment: the Load<Texture2d>() is looking for `ico.xnb` not `ico.png`. The .xnb files are made during build time of any .png file that has been added to the content project properly.

Comment: @SteveH I added the png file to My project as well, this is how it looks like: http://puu.sh/486i6.png

Comment: What's your root directory for of your `Content`? If it's "Content" you need to use: `cursorTex = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Other/ico");`

Answer (score 0):

Load the texture as

```
cursorTex = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ico");
```

instead of

```
cursorTex = Content.Load<Texture2D>("ico.png");
```

**Edit**: seeing you placed your file in a folder, just load it as `...<Texture2D>("other/ico");`